# How do I upgrade a Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, api, upgrade

I have been searching a lot on a search engine and on Facebook's own documentation. I still can't figure out where and how can I upgrade my API for my Facebook app. What should I do? I attach a screenshot on what my API Upgrade Tool dashboard looks like.

[image]

Comment: It seems reasonably clear: you have three things in your API that need to be changed (assuming that your current API is 2.7 and you wish to adhere to 3.1). I don't use this API, but if I did, I guess I'd know what those three things are. Are you able to be more specific about what you do not understand? The first one is `GET` calls to the `{user-id}/albums` endpoint, and it seems to be saying that you use that in 100% of your operations. Is that correct?

Comment: @halfer what is not clear to me is how to update! I don't see any option or button to update. I did not code anything, the only thing I did was create an app for a service I use, according to the instructions I got from the service provider. That was all. I don't even know where I could replace the code. So there is a lot I clearly don't understand here...

Comment: I don't know, but my assumption is that the app you created, in whatever form that takes, is using calls that need to be amended. Are you able to get in touch with the service provider? I wonder if they are making calls on your behalf.

Comment: @halfer, actually your last answer did help. Yes, they were making calls on my behalf (hence why I wasn't understanding a thing) and they have confirmed that they are the ones who need to update and not me. Thank you so very much for your patience! :)